# why i have created secret.py file as requested but still get this error?

Tags: python, automation, aws-secrets-manager

Why am I still getting this error while having created the `secret.py` file as required?

```py
import twitterbot as tb
import secrets, sys

hashtag = sys.argv[1]
credentials = secrets.get_credentials()
bot = tb.Twitterbot(credentials['email'], credentials['password'])
bot.login()
bot.like_retweet(hashtag)
```

```
PS C:\Users\tqnam\OneDrive\Desktop\Quốc Nam\Twitter Automation> python main.py {hashtag}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tqnam\OneDrive\Desktop\Quốc Nam\Twitter Automation\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    credentials = secrets.get_credentials()
AttributeError: module 'secrets' has no attribute 'get_credentials'
PS C:\Users\tqnam\OneDrive\Desktop\Quốc Nam\Twitter Automation>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your ```secrets.py``` code.

Comment: module 'secrets' has no attribute 'get_credentials'